# Why is Google saying that the rich snippet will not display

Tags: google, wordpress, rich-snippets

I am trying to have Google display my author name and picture on my new Wordpress blog.

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

I am submitting my page to the snippet checker and it indeed shows me the result with my name and a picture on the side of that, exactly what I want.

However, near the bottom of the page Google tells me the following:

```
Extracted structured data

hcard

    Warning: The information will not appear as a rich snippet in
    search results, because the marked-up content does 
    not appear to be the main focus of the page.
    More information. (Is this correct? Let us know.)

    Warning: This information will not appear as a rich snippet
    in search results, because it seems to describe an organization. 
    Google does not currently display organization information in rich snippets

    Warning: At least one field must be set for Hcard.

    Warning: Missing required field "name (fn)".
```

I have no idea why Google is complaining, I have set the fn and the vcard:

```
        <span class="author vcard">
            <a class="fn n url" href=">http://www.my_url.co.uk/about" rel="author">
                <?php the_author(); ?>
            </a>
        </span>
```

Also I have no idea why it thinks it is an organisation.

Do I have to worry about this? Perhaps the fact that Google is showing me my picture means they will link to it like that and the warnings are just in case I want to be an organsation.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Schema is way more friendly

Comment: Been toying with your code and I believe the problem is the positioning of the element, I use schema and don't have these problems. If you would like help using schema, let me know and I'll add your code with the schema version.

Comment: @bybe thanks mate, I considered using Schema (I assume you mean Person) but I noticed by checking the view source that most blogs dont have it and it still works. You think I should go for the Schema Person?

Comment: I think you should go for schema blog.

Comment: Let me take a look at your code and I'll put it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason VCard/Hcard Not working**

> Warning: The information will not appear as a rich snippet in
>       search results, because the marked-up content does 
>       not appear to be the main focus of the page.
>       More information. (Is this correct? Let us know.)

The reason you are giving the above problem is because you need to ensure that all vcard data is complete on the page. If you take a look at the very bottom of your page:

```
<footer id="footer" class="footerCopyright source-org vcard copyright">
    <small> </small>
</footer>
```

The thing to notice here is class="footerCopyright source-org ***vcard*** copyright"

Notice how you have the vcard, its incomplete and will cause problems for the rest of the page (remove this vcard and use complete markup, ideally in schema if your switching over and use organization or something), further our discussion comments we discussed about going Schema, by removing the vcard element at the bottom of the page and the rest of the vcards it should work as intended. Let us know. 
**Going Schema**

OK the actual element of the content looks like this:

```
<div class="post-27 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-internet-filters category-internet-monitoring" id="post-27">
  <div class="entry-header">
    <a href="#"><h1 class="entry-title">Title Goes Here</h1></a>
    <div class="entry-meta">
      Posted on 
      <span datetime="2013-05-06T14:50:07+00:00" class="updated entry-date">May 6, 2013</span>
      by      
      <span class="author vcard">
        <a rel="author" href="" class="fn n url">Name</a>
      </span>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
  </div><!-- .entry-header -->
  <div class="entry-content">
  <p><a href="#"><img width="" height="" src="blah.jpg" alt="" class=""></a>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<footer class="entry-meta">
    Post published under <a rel="category tag" title="" href="">Category</a>, <a rel="category tag" title="" href="#">Category</a> by <a href="">Author</a>. Bookmark the <a rel="bookmark" title="" href=""></a>.   
      </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</div>
```

You can edit the template files of WordPress and have it include the markup for blog which will work with the author markup as well as some other markups like keywords which I have added for your consideration, This example was covered in a question I asked a while back: [Using Schema for Blogging Article Vs Blogposting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46680/using-schema-for-blogging-article-vs-blogposting), below is what you would need to change to get it working with your current setup.

**Change 1**

*From:* `<div class="post-27 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-internet-filters category-internet-monitoring" id="post-27">`

*To:* `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" class="post-27 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-internet-filters category-internet-monitoring" id="post-27">`

**Change 2**

From: `<a href="#"><h1 class="entry-title">Title Goes Here</h1></a>`

To: `<h1 itemprop="name"><a rel="bookmark" title="Title Description" href="#">Article Header</a></h1>`

**Change 3**

From: `<span datetime="2013-05-06T14:50:07+00:00" class="updated entry-date">May 6, 2013</span>`

To: `<time itemprop="datePublished">2013-01-25</time>`

**Change 3**

From: `<span datetime="2013-05-06T14:50:07+00:00" class="updated entry-date">May 6, 2013</span>`

To: `<time itemprop="datePublished">2013-01-25</time>`

**Change 3**

From:

```
<span class="author vcard">
    <a rel="author" href="" class="fn n url">Name</a>
</span>
```

To: `<a rel="author" href="#">Author Name</a>`

***Alternatively***

Alternatively you could use better markup and provide even more data like so:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <div class="post-27 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-internet-filters category-internet-monitoring" id="post-27">
    <header class="entry-header">
      <h1 itemprop="name"><a rel="bookmark" title="Title Description" href="#">Article Header</a></h1>
        <dl>
            <dt>Publish Date:</dt>
            <dd><time itemprop="datePublished">2013-01-25</time></dd>
            <dt>Author</dt>
            <dd><a rel="author" href="#">Author Name</a></dd>
        </dl>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
      <aside>A image that floats left or right</aside>
      <p>Article Contents Here</a>
    </div>
    <footer class="entry-meta">
      <dl>
        <dt>Post published under</dt>
        <dd itemprop="keywords"><a rel="category" title="Title Description" href="#">Category 1</a></dd>
        <dd itemprop="keywords"><a rel="category" title="Title Description" href="#">Category 1</a></dd>
        <dt>Bookmark this page:</dt>
        <dd><a rel="bookmark" title="" href=""></a></dd>
      </dl>
    </footer>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Thats most kind of you, giving it a bash, update you soon!

Comment: I have updated like you suggested but still not change :( even more so it is complaining of missing data now

Comment: Taking a look now

Comment: cheers! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I believe the problem may be to do with the hcard, hatom-feed markup still being on the page, you would need to remove these elements as currently they are incomplete.

Comment: ok, and by hatom-feed you mean what?

Comment: http://technotes.khitrenovich.com/fix-missing-required-fields-warnings-rich-snippets-testing-tool/ This is for the hcard and for the hatom-feed, I believe the class that is causing this is henty

Comment: <div class="post-27 post type-post status-publish format-standard **hentry** category-internet-filters category-internet-monitoring" id="post-27">

Comment: Ya, Just tested you'd need to remove all vcard elements such as entry-title, entry-content. It would seem that your template is very microdata enabled and your need to get rid of all elements, if its too much hassle I found http://technotes.khitrenovich.com/fix-missing-required-fields-warnings-rich-snippets-testing-tool/ and http://www.ilmigo.com/fix-hfeed-warning-field-set-hatomentry.html which should be able to resolve the vcard issue.

Comment: Removed it all but still not working, shall i give up?

Comment: Not just yet, lets go chat since this is getting rather long. I'm narrowing down your problem now. Its not the content element its surronding elements adding code that im filtering thou now for ya

Comment: OK you don't have enough reputation to start of a chat room but anyway! I've narrowed down the problem for you and now I'll edit my question. Edited my answer, take a look at the very top, this should solve your problem... ;)

Comment: You are unbelievable, I have spent 5 hours on this and you solve it   in half an hour!!!! Brilliant !!!

Comment: Your very welcome ;)

Comment: @Jake no problem! done ;)

Comment: its a full service you offer ;) have a nice weekend